# Stripping empty columns from CALS

Tags: xslt

I had a similar question to this answered here 
[Strip empty columns from calstable model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756558/strip-empty-columns-from-calstable-model)

Essentially the same problem with slightly more complexity:
I have a bunch of CALS model tables across multiple XML files. Some of these have an empty final column such as in this example

> ```
>          <table frame="none">
>             <tgroup cols="4" colsep="0" rowsep="0">
>                <colspec colname="1" colnum="1" colwidth="75pt"/>
>                <colspec colname="2" colnum="2" colwidth="63pt" align="center"/>
>                <colspec colname="3" colnum="3" colwidth="63pt" align="center"/>
>                <colspec colname="4" colnum="4" colwidth="63pt"/>
>                <thead>
>                   <row valign="bottom">
>                      <entry> </entry>
>                      <entry>No. 9</entry>
>                      <entry>No. 10</entry>
>                      <entry> </entry>
>                   </row>
>                </thead>
>                <tbody>
>                   <row>
>                      <entry>Max. size:</entry>
>                      <entry>10.5 m.</entry>
>                      <entry>6.7 m.</entry>
>                      <entry> </entry>
>                   </row>
>                   <row>
>                      <entry>Length:</entry>
>                      <entry>210 m.</entry>
>                      <entry>100 m.</entry>
>                      <entry> </entry>
>                   </row>
>                   <row>
>                      <entry>Depth:</entry>
>                      <entry>11.0</entry>
>                      <entry>7.0</entry>
>                      <entry> </entry>
>                   </row>
>                </tbody>
>             </tgroup>
>          </table>
> ```

I would like to delete the final empty column. The answer in the other post solved many examples. But where the tables used merged cells in their structure , it didn't work.

A straddle row would be coded as

> ```
>                   <row>
>                      <entry namest="1" nameend="3">Notes: This table is short</entry>
>                      <entry> </entry>
>                   </row>
> ```

What adaptations would I need to make to the other solution to account for the straddle rows?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the stylesheet from [JLRishe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756558/strip-empty-columns-from-calstable-model)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- This key will allow us to select all the entries in a column based on their
       column  number -->
    <xsl:key name="kColumn" match="entry"
        use="count(. | preceding-sibling::entry[not(@namest)]) 
        + count(preceding-sibling::entry[@namest])
        + sum(preceding-sibling::entry/@nameend)
        - sum(preceding-sibling::entry/@namest)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tgroup">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <!-- Select colspecs whose column isn't all blank -->
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                select="colspec[key('kColumn', position())[normalize-space(.)]]" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::colspec)]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="colspec">
        <colspec colname="{position()}" colnum="{position()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                select="@*[local-name() != 'colname' and local-name() != 'colnum']" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </colspec>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Omit entries that belong to all-blank columns -->
    <xsl:template match="entry[not(key('kColumn', count(. | preceding-sibling::entry[not(@namest)]) 
        + count(preceding-sibling::entry[@namest])
        + sum(preceding-sibling::entry/@nameend)
        - sum(preceding-sibling::entry/@namest))[normalize-space(.)])]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have done a couple of tests with `@namest` and `@nameend`. I'm not sure if this code would work if `@morerows` is present.